# Does Stripe have webhook for usage record?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, payment, stripes

Stripe uses webhooks to notify application when an event happens in the account. Webhooks are particularly useful for asynchronous events like when a customer’s bank confirms a payment, a customer disputes a charge, a recurring payment succeeds, or when collecting subscription payments etc.

But, does stripe have any webhook to inform application for usage record pricing model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no webhook for usage record today in Stripe's API. This API is used at a higher volume that most APIs and reporting an event for every usage record would likely be unsustainable on your servers and Stripe's.

The best option is to either track the records yourself as you create those or use the summary API: https://stripe.com/docs/api/usage_records/subscription_item_summary_list

Comment: Note that it is *your code* that is updating the usage records - it makes little sense to have a webhook call to tell you that *your code* just took an action.  Webhooks *generally* inform you of events that happen *asynchronously* to your code.